# Limit of 2 functions of the same independent variable

Tags: calculus

I am a high school begginer in calculus.as I was reading one of my textbooks on calculus and stumbled on one poorly explained rule:

*Two functions of the same independent variable are said to be ultimately equal when as the independent variable approaches indefinitely near its assigned value the limit of their ratio is unity.
Thus $\lim_{\theta\to 0}$ ${sin(\theta)\over\theta}$=1*

can someone please explain why $\lim_{x\to a}\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}=1$

Comment: So what do you need explain, exactly? The definition of "ultimately equal" or why $\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin{\theta}}{\theta} = 1$ ?

Comment: I would say that this is an attempt to define "ultimately equal".  Thus $\sin \theta $ and $\theta$ are ultimately equal at $0$.  This is not a standard phrase...I think most mathematicians would prefer to stick with $\lim_{x\to a}\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}=1$.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Matti P I need an explanation of the "ultimately equal"

Comment: Well, essentially the text is defining "ultimately equal" as how lulu phrased it. So
$$
f(x)\quad \text{and}\quad g(x) \quad \text{are ultimately equal} \quad \Leftrightarrow \qquad \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1
$$
So that's just a definition of a pair of words. I don't see how more explanation would be needed. Is there still something unclear about this for you?